# intermittent slow starter cranking on saab 9-3 diesel

Tags: battery, diesel, starter, saab, 9-3

Sometimes , usually after a long run the starter turns very slowly like it has a flat battery. If I am lucky turning the key again a few times it will turn the engine at normal speed and it starts. It can then go for weeks starting normally before it happens again. I don't think its the battery because a flat battery would stay flat and it would never start till charged. I am thinking starter or solenoid. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

My bet is a loose or corroded connection. Leaning toward loose if it is intermittent.

I would try cleaning the battery, starter and ground connections of the starting system.

Comment: Or better yet a corroded B+ or ground cable (the whole cable) which increases resistance with temperature.  Use the famous (but often misunderstood) magic "Voltage Drop" test to diagnose this.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue on saab 9-3 2007. Problem was a faulty cables between battery and chassis. Garage has added additional cable connection between battery and engine (ground) instead of replacing complete wire lines and voila, it starts perfectly again.